# Computer rename after domain join on AWS

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a windows domain infrastructure deployed on AWS EC2 instances. What we want to achieve is to create a custom sysprepped image that when launching new instances those instances will auto join the domain and then rename themselves based on the region, availability zone and server name defined in AWS console.

The first step is already implemented by using the join domain component added to sysprep2008.xml like below:

```
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-UnattendedJoin" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Identification>
        <UnsecureJoin>False</UnsecureJoin>
        <Credentials>
          <Domain>dc.connatix.com</Domain>
          <Password>####</Password>
          <Username>####</Username>
        </Credentials>
        <JoinDomain>####</JoinDomain>
        <MachineObjectOU>OU=Servers,DC=dc,DC=####,DC=com</MachineObjectOU>
      </Identification>
</component>
```

For the rename operation we tried a lot of options:
1. execute a powershell script after sysprep that will retrieve a list of scripts to be applied from the domain controller and execute them one by one but Get-AdDomainController returns nothing in this step
2. Add a scheduled task through group policy that will execute this script: this is not working since we cannot add a task that will run under domain admin account through group policy
3. Add a startup script through group policy but again this is not running under the domain admin account.

The script used in all those scenarios is below and it's running great when running from an authenticated user.

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "####" -Force -AsPlainText
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("####", $mypwd)

Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey #### -SecretKey #### -StoreAs default

$InstanceId = (Invoke-RestMethod 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').ToString()
$AvailabilityZone = (Invoke-RestMethod 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone').ToString().ToLower()
$Region = $AvailabilityZone.Substring(0,$AvailabilityZone.Length-1)
$computer = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem

$Tags = Get-EC2Tag -Filters @{Name='resource-id';Value=$InstanceId} -Region $Region
$InstanceName = $AvailabilityZone + '-' + ($Tags | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'Name'}).Value.ToLower()

$computerName = $computer.Name.ToLower();
If($InstanceName -ne $null) {
    If ($computerName -ne $InstanceName) {
        Rename-Computer -NewName $InstanceName -DomainCredential $mycreds -Restart
    }
}
```

How do you think we can accomplish this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure if you're doing this already or not, but there may be an additional "gotcha" in EC2 where [the computer name is (conditionally) reset on each boot by the EC2 Config Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html#UsingConfigInterface_WinAMI). You can disable it from the service's dialog.

Comment: Hello Anthony, we already have auto computer name reset on ec2 but I would like that the computer name would be the EC2 tag set in the console. We want this because we would like to do something like the following: if the computer name is let's say WEB-PROD-X to automatically install IIS, deploy our web apps and add under load balancer. If it's SERV-PROD-X to automatically install our custom windows services and so forth. It's very important that we maintain our naming convention

Comment: Can you clarify what error you received with the script you posted and when? Or did you in fact eventually get this working? I'm about to embark on a similar endeavor but before I start going down the same path to troubleshoot if you did get it going would appreciate a follow-up. Thank you.

Comment: hi ss2k. I gave up making this work because it was really time consuming being very hard to simulate. I will let you know if I'm going to restart working on it and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at gMSA, while it is supported in 2008 forest, it became even better with 2012 & R2. You create a gMSA account that belongs to the domain admins group and assosicate that gMSA account with domain controllers.

Then use a powershell script to create a scheduled task (only way to create it using a gMSA account). When the task runs, the password is automatically taken care of by the domain controller.